# What is the proper way to manage a company's SSL certificates?

Tags: tls, certificates, key-management

Is there a way/software to manage and sign multiple SSL certificates? We have many intranet web applications that show the certificate error risk in the web browser. I have been googling a lot but SSL certificates still mystify me, I know how to make one with digicert or keystore explorer, but what is the professional way to manage them?. We have an .exe for turning .csr files into .cert files with supposedly valid CA, but we still get invalid certificate warnings, plus that .exe is not official and is now unsupported.

Most especially does anyone know of an enterprise solution? I've seen several cloud services have their certificate managers but I think a SaaS or on-prem solution is better, we have machines in all cloud vendors and on-prem so managing all our certs from, let's say AWS for example, might lead to issues?

Comment: Product recommendations are off-topic here. A term you might use when searching for this is [pki software](https://www.google.com/search?q=pki+software)

Comment: Why not use a wildcard certificate?..

Comment: You might want to consider using [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) as your certificate authority, then automating your certificate issuing/renewal process using an [ACME](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/client-options/) client such as [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/), or another [lighter-weight ACME client](https://github.com/diafygi/acme-tiny).